# Control two or more channel relay using a single signal pin from an Arduino

Tags: arduino, relay, arduino-uno

I would like control a four-channel relay using a single signal pin from an Arduino.

Is there any way to do it?

Using external components, is this possible with any PWM pins or something else?

Comment: What is a "four channel relay"? Do you mean a 4PST or 4PDT relay? Or do you mean some kind of module with four separate relays in it? Or something more exotic like a 4-position stepper switch?

Comment: 4 channel relay module, with 4 seperate relayin it.

Comment: Do you want to operate the four relays together or independently - together is easy, but independent operation would be more complex.

Comment: i would like to operate it independently

Comment: Do you need them to be completely independent, or will, for instance, only one of them ever be energized at a time? That makes things slightly easier if so (you can avoid using a DAC and sort of emulate a stepper switch instead).

Comment: Is there any way? Sure there is. Many. Please rule out most of them by specifying what is allowed and what is not. You could add another MCU and communicate UART between them, for example. Is that a viable solution?

Answer (score 3):

It's definitely possible.  You could make a PWM DAC and use comparators to trip at the desired threshold.

This approach will be easier if you only need one relay on at a time.  It could be expanded and decoded to give independent control, but you'd need 16 levels.  To make a PWM DAC, you use a PWM output from your uC and a low-pass filter.  The PWM frequency is set to be much higher than the filter cutoff, so the output is effectively DC.

Then you set up a series of comparators.  You'd need maybe 3 window comparators for the mid 3 bands and a single comparator for the top band. You might be able to do with fewer comparators depending on your switching requirements.

Then set your PWM to give an output in the center of the desired window to turn on the relay you want on.

If you need complete independent control of each relay, this approach will work:

You could also use a digital one-wire interface to a port expander like this one: [Maxim Port Expander](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/ibutton-one-wire/memory-products/DS2408.html)

You'd have to write some code to bit-bang the one-wire interface but seems pretty straightforward.

The interface is completely described in the Maxim datasheet at the link, so I won't bother to do it here.

There are other approaches as well, but those may be the easiest.

Comment: Thanks, could you be more specific, with some guided steps or something

Comment: @vishnus Just added more information.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to get it down to *two* pins (I know you said one, but if you can deal with two, this may be worth considering) with a bit of simple logic circuitry:

Use a serial-in/parallel-out shift register. Use one pin on your microcontroller to send the data, and another one to clock in each bit. To avoid needing a third pin to latch the new outputs, have the latch input hooked up to a divide-by-four counter that can latch the shift register when the clock goes low after the fourth pulse. That way, it will just automatically latch after you've clocked in all four bits.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine clock and data in a single signal and reconstruct both using an R/C lowpass filter for the data status. A shift register can receive this and provide parallel data outputs.

[image: schematic]

1. Assume the idle signal level of the MCU output is high, then the data input of the shift register is also high. The shift register reads the data input at rising edges of the MCU signal.
2. When the MCU creates short negative pulses, here < 10 us, with a distance > 30 us, the shift register clocks in high bits, because the voltage across C2 cannot fall enough to be read as "low".
3. When the MCU creates longer negative pulses, > 30 us, the shift register will clock in low bits.
4. You can clock out 4 bits using an interval of e.g. 50 us per bit using different low periods for the data. If you do this fast enough, the relays will not react on short output changes.
5. This timing is just an example, you can use other R/C values to use 1 MBit or more and use a SPI MOSI output for convenience and use all 8 outputs of this chip.

Answer (score 0):

Get a relay module that accepts serial commands, I have a 16 port one here. but smaller exist.

A UART only needs one pin to send commands, if your hardware UART is busy, you'll need to do a software one, fortunately you only need the sending side, and that's the easiest side to do in software.